# Excel cell is magically populated with formula after another cell gets data entered

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Some mysterious behavior within a simple worksheet (Excel 2013 - Win7, but also continues if workbook is opened on Excel 2019 - Win10):
Cells in column "A" are getting populated with a formula after I enter a number in cell of column "C".
For example:
When I enter the number 123456 in C23, the following is automatically entered into a previously blank A23: =HYPERLINK("http://gigapan.com/gigapans/"&C23,C23) which is what I want, but how is it happening automatically? There are NO conditional formattings (that I can find), NO Worksheet_Change VBA subs running (NO VBA code at all for this workbook). The result is what I want, but it is driving me crazy not knowing how it got set up this way!!! Took the xlsx file to another computer with no Personal.xlsb to interfere and same behavior. Suggestions?

[Excel example screenshot...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYk1g.jpg)

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the file, but I would guess spill range. Try to copy it and strip it down to just a pure example and post it on google drive or something.

Comment: Excel will often automatically copy an existing formula down if you add data to an existing range of cells and the formula can logically be extended to the next row to match the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behaviour, controlled by the option Advanced > Extend data range formats and formulas. Described at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/advanced-options-33244b32-fe79-4579-91a6-48b3be0377c4

Comment: Totally! Solved the issue.  I must have created the spreadsheet on one system (newer) where that setting is the default, and moved to another system (with older Excel) and the setting was kept. As the info states at the link you provided "...To be extended, formats and formulas must appear in **bold** at least three of the five last rows preceding the new row.**bold**" that is why I did not notice the behavior when I first started entering data. Thanks!